# SonarQube - Fail to connect to update center with no proxy

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I installed SonarQube 5.6.3 and when I go to Update Center, I can only see "Installed" plugins. But the other tabs don't show anything (0 shown). **I'm not using a proxy**. The logs show the following:

```
ERROR web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Fail to connect to update center
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
    at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader.failToDownload(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:157) ~[sonar-core-5.6.3.jar:na]
```

I tried downloading manually the file *https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties* using wget and it worked fine.

Why is not working from UpdateCenter? Do I need to specify anything in sonar.properties file?
The only line related to Update Center in sonar.properties is: *sonar.updatecenter.activate=true*

Comment: Does your computer/server where SonarQube has been installed have access to internet ?
Does the wget command is working on this instance ?

Comment: Can you also send the full logs please ?

Comment: @Eric, yes the server has access to Internet, and wget works fine when downloading the file _update-center.properties_ manually

Comment: @Simon, sure. How can I attach the file here? Sorry for asking, but it's the first time I participate in stackoverflow, and I'm not familiar with the options. I don't think I should paste a long output from the logs. Or should I ?  :)

Comment: You can past logs to gist.github.com and give the link.

Comment: @Simon, here is the link to the logs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b703ba493a02613aa1531f63e8435913

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using IBM JDK that does not behave like Oracle JDK with TLS connections. And without setting com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS to true, the application is unable to connect to the Update Center that is using TLS 1.2 (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html#matchsslcontext_tls)

Adding **-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true** to **sonar.web.javaOpts** in conf/sonar.properties will solve your issue.

I highly recommand to add this property (-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true) to sonar.web.javaOpts, sonar.ce.javaOpts and sonar.search.javaOpts

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I followed the suggestion from Eric, and installed Java from Oracle, instead of IBM. Before doing that, I tried adding **-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true** to java options, but nothing changed. As soon as I changed to Oracle JRE, the Update Center started working as expected.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set your http and https proxy configuration in sonar.properties:

```
http.proxyHost=<host>
http.proxyPort=<port>
http.proxyUser=<username>
http.proxyPassword=<password>    
https.proxyHost=<host>
https.proxyPort=<port>
https.proxyUser=<username>
https.proxyPassword=<password>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you try any options available here, please check the internet connectivity to sonarqube machine and check(refresh) the ALM configuration again.